# ReverseGeocodeLocation completions usage in viewDidLoad() swift4.1

Tags: ios, swift, reverse-geocoding, completionhandler

Swift version: 4.1

Hello I am a bit more than beginner in swift. Working in an "order application by user locations". Which I control user "country" and "city" name by `reversegeocodelocation function` before user give order. And write those values in firebase realtime database childs.

my data structure is like

```
 -TR
   -Ankara
       -userID
           -Order(consist of user lat, user long, user mail, userOrder)
```

It is okay I did that users can order and cancel his/her orders. But also I want to check if users close their phone and return the app, the app should check the database and if there is order given by current user `uID` it must change the button label, `buttonToCancelState = true`, and image of our mascot.

This is how I get user `coord` for order and "countrycode" and "city" for data structure name.

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations [0]

    if let coord = manager.location?.coordinate {
        userLocation = coord

    }


    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) {(placemark, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("there is an error")
        } else {

        var placeMark: CLPlacemark?
        placeMark = placemark?[0]


        // City
        if let city = placeMark?.locality {
            self.userCity = city as String

        }

        // Country
        if let country = placeMark?.isoCountryCode {
            self.userCountry = country as String
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I use these "country" and "city" in "order button" like example;

```
            orderHasBeenCalled = true
            buttonLabelText.text = "CANCEL/EDIT"
            imgView.image = UIImage(named: "...")
            let orderRequestDictionary: [String:Any] = ["..."]
            databaseREF.child(userCountry).child(userCity).child(userID!).setValue(orderRequestDictionary)
```

it works flawlessly user can send order, delete it even when user logout it deleted too, (the whole codes did not included)

now the problem is I want to check if the users have an order when the  `viewDidLoad()` loads for this I am using

```
if let userID = FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        databaseRef.child(userCountry).child(userCity).queryOrdered(byChild: userID!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.OrderHasBeenCalled = true
            self.buttonLabelText.text = "CANCEL/EDIT"
            self.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "...")
            databaseRef.child(self.userCountry).child(self.userCity).removeAllObservers()
        })
   }
```

Now the problem is as I read in internet `reversegeocode` is asynchronous or something like that and as seems it is not ready when the viewDidLoad() load, "code for check if there is order" crash the app because it finds no value to search the names in childs.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
```

To make use of userCountry and userCity in orderbutton I define them before viewDidLoad()

```
var userCountry = String()
var userCity = String()
```

I have tried many ways but didn't really figure it out that how can I get reversegeocode completion in viewdidload(). I tried `viewDidAppear()` too btw but it gives userCountry() and userCity() nil too.

I hope my question is clear and easly understandable. Will be very appreciated if answers will be in that way. Did a lot of researh in the internet some I try, some I did not understand or did not know how can I even try. The last place that my hope shine is stack overflow. Thanks by now for all the people whose Kindly responds my question.

Comment: No. Is is because you're redeclaring it inside your viewController... I will update the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change a little the approach. Once working with async functions you must avoid sync request values.

There are several ways to make nested calls from async functions, from your code I arrived at this approach, adapt to your need and it should work.

```
/////////attention the scope (must be above class declaration)
typealias CompletionGetAddress = (_ userCity : String?, _ userCountry: String?, _ success: Bool) -> Void
var userLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
//

class viewController: ... {
func viewDidLoad() {

    yourLocationManager.requestLocation()

    // you should implement some code to ensure your userLocation from your locationManager is not nil and a valid location

    if let userID = FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        if self.userCity != "" {
            databaseRef.child(userCountry).child(userCity).queryOrdered(byChild: userID!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                self.OrderHasBeenCalled = true
                self.buttonLabelText.text = "CANCEL/EDIT"
                self.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "...")
                databaseRef.child(self.userCountry).child(self.userCity).removeAllObservers()
            })
        } else {
            getAddress { (city, country, success) in
                if success {
                    self.userCity = city
                    self.userCountry = country
                    databaseRef.child(userCountry).child(userCity).queryOrdered(byChild: userID!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                        self.OrderHasBeenCalled = true
                        self.buttonLabelText.text = "CANCEL/EDIT"
                        self.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "...")
                        databaseRef.child(self.userCountry).child(self.userCity).removeAllObservers()
                    })
                }
            }           
        }
    }
} 
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations [0]

    if let coord = manager.location?.coordinate {
        userLocation = coord /// attention here 

    }
}


func getAddress(completion: @escaping CompletionGetAddress) {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) {(placemark, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("there is an error")
            completion(nil, nil, false)
        } else {
            var city: String = ""
            var country: String = ""
            var placeMark: CLPlacemark?
            placeMark = placemark?[0]
            // City
            if let c = placeMark?.locality {
                city = c
            }
            // Country
            if let c = placeMark?.isoCountryCode {
                country = c
            }
            completion(city, country, true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adapting will respond as soon as possible

Comment: Just to be sure, place the `typealias` declaration on top of class to be global

Comment: I edited my question. If you can check in your free time it would be awesome. Even, if you can't check, you gave me the code that I could not find anywhere. I am really appreciated.

Comment: where before was `userLocation` now is `drinkerLocation` (better drinker than user but I think there is a mistyping)

Comment: change `class viewController: ... {
    var userLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()` by `var userLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()    
    class viewController: ... {` see ? Above class declaration, and change your `didUpdateLocation` drinker....

Comment: I editten as you said so but I think you should look again I feel I am over questioning if it is please accept my sorry. I am so happy and thank you again.

Comment: The first adaptation of mine was wrong now it works flawlessly thanks for all your help if I can do anything for you just let me know, giving point or something like that to you

Comment: Glad you could handle it by yourself. Accepting the answer is already awesome. Thank you and hope you step forward in your project